# Using hadoop distcp to copy data to s3 block filesystem: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use hadoop's `distcp` to copy data from HDFS to S3 (not S3N). My understanding is that using the `s3://` protocol, Hadoop will store the individual blocks on S3, and each S3 'file' will effectively be an HDFS block.

Hadoop version is 2.2.0 running on Amazon EMR.

However, trying to do a simple `distcp`, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 71C64ECE79FCC244, AWS Error Code: InvalidRequest, AWS Error Message: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120, S3 Extended Request ID: uAnvxtrNolvs0qm6htIrKjpD0VFxzjqgIeN9RtGFmXflUHDcSqwnZGZgWt5PwoTy
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:619)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2943)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.copy(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy11.copy(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.rename(NativeS3FileSystem.java:1217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.promoteTmpToTarget(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
```

Some of my source files are >5GB. Looking at the error, it seems that distcp is trying to blindly copy files from HDFS into S3, as if it were using the S3 Native filesystem. Because of the files that are >5GB, this is failing, as S3 doesn't support put requests >5GB.

Why is this happening? I would have thought that distcp would try to put the individual blocks onto S3, and these should only be 64MB (my HDFS blocksize).

Comment: Hadoop's file system interface doesn't care about the block level when you are interacting with it (why should it?). I guess you will need to manually split the file.

Comment: So how do I use the `s3://` filesystem? How do I copy files into it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to write files with size > 4GB - one must use multi-part uploads. This seems to have been fixed in Hadoop version 2.4.0 (see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9454).

That said - this is one of the reasons why it makes sense to use AWS native Hadoop offerings like EMR and Qubole. They are already setup to deal with such idiosyncracies. (Full Disclosure - I am one of the founders @Qubole). In addition to vanilla multipart uploads - we also support streaming multi part uploads - where the file is continuously uploaded to S3 in small chunks even as it is being generated. (in vanilla multipart upload - we first wait for the file to be fullly generated and only then upload in chunks to S3).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example from wiki : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3

```
% ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop distcp hdfs://domU-12-31-33-00-02-DF:9001/user/nutch/0070206153839-1998 s3://123:456@nutch/
```